# CakePHP Cakepdf(Plugin) error Missing View 'Create PDF for file storage'

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am using `cakePHP 2.6` and `CakePdf` plugin. While generating and saving i came across a problem of `Missing View`

**Code Controller**

```
public function testpdf() {
    $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
    $CakePdf->template('newsletter', 'default');
    // write it to file directly
    $pdf = $CakePdf->write(APP . 'files' . DS . 'newsletter.pdf');
}
```

**Error Recived:**

```
Missing View

Error: The view for AdminsController::testpdf() was not found.

Confirm you have created the file: Pdf/newsletter.ctp in one of the following paths:

/var/www/html/cake2pluginsEdited/app/View/Plugin/AdminUsers/Pdf/newsletter.ctp
/var/www/html/cake2pluginsEdited/app/Plugin/AdminUsers/View/Pdf/newsletter.ctp
/var/www/html/cake2pluginsEdited/app/View/Pdf/newsletter.ctp
```

I have created `newsletter.ctp` on all the given paths in above error still its providing me the same error. Already given `write` permission to whole `app` folder. Also gone through the issues on `Git Hub` [Issues CAkePdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/issues) Cannot find a solution, any pointers will be a great help.

The code `Render as PDF` works fine but cannot get it saved on server.

Comment: If these files really do exist, then it's likely that they have the wrong permissions set, ie they are not readable by the user that PHP runs under.

Comment: i am running as root user and every file ha `777` permission

Comment: Seems like the issue is that there isn't a 'testpdf' view file. Try redirecting to another action after writing the pdf.